# Vim switch statement cindent options

Tags: indentation

I want my C code indented as follows:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Instead of this:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        {
            break;
        }
}
```

I looked through cinoptions, but didn't find what I need. I'm looking for some options I missed or other indentation script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess brackets ate optional for `case` blocks so you can avoid them.

Comment: @SibiCoder: I don't think it's the point of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution with custom indent script:

```
setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/

setlocal cindent
setlocal cinoptions=Ls,t0,(0

setlocal indentexpr=GetCaseBlockCorrectedIndent()
setlocal indentkeys=!^F,0{,0},0),0#,o,O,e,:

function! s:PrevNonBlankOrComment(startlnum)
    let lnum = a:startlnum
    while lnum > 0
        let lnum = prevnonblank(lnum)
        if (getline(lnum) =~ '^\s*\(/\|\*\)')
            let lnum -= 1
        else
            break
        endif
    endwhile
    return lnum
endfunction

function! GetCaseBlockCorrectedIndent()
    let lnum = v:lnum
    let prevlnum = s:PrevNonBlankOrComment(lnum - 1)
    let idnt = cindent(v:lnum)
    let adj = 0
    if getline(prevlnum) =~ '^\s*case\>' && getline(lnum) =~ '^\s*{'
       let adj = -&shiftwidth
    endif
    return idnt + adj
endfunction
```

Comment: I desire the same indenting, but this solution doesn't work for [multiple scoped cases](https://gist.github.com/idbrii/ef44340d4f955f0a7af4656618e7ed92). Does that work for you? (I tried vim with just vim-sensible and this code, but no luck.)

Comment: @idbrii In the absence of a reply from the OP, you should try out [@D.BenKnoble's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27336/343) and see if that works better for you.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible *as is*, you can work around that though.

---

For your current example you can set

```
:set  cino={-s
```

This will reindent each `{`/`}` pair found to reduce the shift width setting. This will work on the example you gave:

```
switch (x)
{
  case 1:
    break;
  case 2:
  {
      break;
  }
}
```

But not on an example with more complex syntax:

```
switch (x)
{
  case 1:
    break;
  case 2:
  {
      break;
      if( 1 )
    {
        //stuff
    }
  }
}
```

---

Apparently, by looking at [`:h cindent`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#cindent), Vim prefers the curly brace on the same line as the statement.

So I would recommand using the following formatting instead:

```
switch (x) {

  case 1:
    break;

  case 2: {
    break;
  }

}
```

With this, you can set `cino=l1` and indent will be:

```
switch (x) {

  case 1:
    break;

  case 2: {
    break;
  }

}
```

Again, it might not suit your coding style but AFAIK, it the best way to properly indent the case statement.

Answer (score 3):

A solution I discovered while answering a duplicate: it should be faster than the existing answer, as it uses just a couple of matches/builtin functions, rather than looping over lines. The algorithm is simpler, too. However, it may not work if there are blank lines or comments between the `{` and the `case`, or comments at the front of those lines—I would consider both so rare to not warrant fixing those issues, but if you need it, it's doable.

---

I put together a little function that defaults to using `cindent()` for the indent, unless we are indenting a `{` line that directly follows a case statement (I've been twiddling a lot with `indentexpr` lately):

```
function s:indent(lnum, offset) abort
  return a:lnum <= 0
        \ ? indent('.')
        \ : indent(a:lnum) + a:offset
endfunction

function! c#myindentexpr(lnum) abort
  if a:lnum <= 1
    return cindent(a:lnum)
  endif
  if getline(a:lnum) =~# '^\s*{' && getline(a:lnum-1) =~# '^\s*case'
    return s:indent(a:lnum-1, 0)
  else
    return cindent(a:lnum)
  endif
endfunction
```

Drop it in `~/.vim/autoload/c.vim`, and put the following line in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`:

```
setlocal indentexpr=c#myindentexpr(v:lnum)
```

You probably want to set `b:undo_ftplugin` as well.

---

I tested this on a couple of simple cases and it seems to be working.