# How to change indentation in "case" with curly braces?

Tags: indentation

The default is this:

```
switch(x)
{
    case a:
        {
            y();
        }
}
```

But I need this:

```
switch(x)
{
    case a:
    {
        y();
    }
}
```

---

With `:set cindent` and `:set  cino={-s` this is the result (indentation of switch's scope is wrong this time):

```
int main()
{
    switch(X)
{
    case a:
    {
            //...
    }

    case b:
    {
            //...
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please add a question to your question. How does [Indent multiple lines quickly in vi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/235839) fail to solve your problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim switch statement cindent options](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8718/vim-switch-statement-cindent-options)

Comment: @Quasímodo: Thanks for your suggestion. No,

Comment: @Rich: thanks, No, that solves the first case, but fails at others.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I think there's only one case in your question. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Rich: sorry, I confused with another topic, I edited the post to clarify the problem with :set  cino={-s which suggested at that link.

Comment: @ridan89390 Thanks for the clarification. It looks your question is the same as that one, but none of the several answers there entirely solve the general case. Note that if you _always_ use blocks after your case labels, a simple `:set cino+==0` will suffice. If you sometimes use bare statements though, you're going to need a custom `indentexpr` like the accepted answer (but which solves that one's issues): I don't think it's possible with simple tweaks to `'cinoptions'`.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote as this question could still do with a full, general-case solution.

Comment: @Rich: thanks for `:set cino+==0` it works for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can align statements following the `case` label with the [`=N`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#cino-%3D) member of [`'cinoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27cinoptions%27). The following will fix your specific example:

```
:set cinoptions+==0
```

Unfortunately, it breaks indentation if you *don't* use a block:

```
switch(x)
{
    case a:
    {
        y();
    }
    case b:
    y();
}
```

You've [indicated in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27310/q-how-to-change-indentation-in-case-with-curly-braces/27312#comment49143_27310) that this solution works for you, though, so I'm adding it as an answer.

See this [very-nearly-identical question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8718/vim-switch-statement-cindent-options) (actually, just a more general case) for various solutions to that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation of C/C++ code is typically done by enabling the `'cindent'` option (built-in to Vim), which is in turn controlled by options set in [`'cinoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#cinoptions-values).

There are two interesting settings in `'cinoptions'` that somewhat do what you want.

The first is [`:set cinoptions==0`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#cino-%3D), which instructs Vim to not indent the block under a `case` statement. So you do get this effect:

```
case a:
{
    y();
    break;
}
```

On the downside, when you don't use a block starting with `{`, then what you get is:

```
case a:
y();
break;
```

Which looks wrong...

Then there's [`:set cinoptions=l1`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#cino-l), which doesn't do *exactly* what you described here, but on the other hand it works well for when the `{` is opened on the same line as the `case` statement.

So you get:

```
case a: {
    y();
    break;
}
```

And if you omit the braces, then you get:

```
case a:
    y();
    break;
```

But unfortunately it doesn't help in the case where the `{` is opened on a line of its own, below the `case` statement.

These two options affect `case` statements exclusively, so they don't affect any other `{` blocks connected to any other statements (I see you found `:set  cino={-s` but that affects the `{`s elsewhere.)

It's theoretically possible to get *exactly* what you need by writing an indentation function and setting `'indentexpr'` (instead of using the built-in `'cindent'`), but this would require you to write Vimscript to essentially reimplement all the built-in features of `'cindent'` as well, which would surely be a herculean task... Probably best is to settle for one of the options above, or perhaps manually fix the indentation (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and similar keystrokes) when you use blocks inside `case` statements, particularly if you don't do it too often.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply, what is the difference between `:set cinoptions==0` and `:set cinoptions+==0` which @Rich suggested?

Comment: Using `+=` on an option will add to the existing list of options. Since `'cinoptions'` is typically empty (and it's empty by default), both will do the same. If `'cinoptions'` had previous settings in it, then `=` will drop the existing ones, while `+=` will preserve them. I guess I wrote my answer on the assumption you would set one of these options in your vimrc, and if you had more to set, you'd set it all in a single command...

Comment: See `:help :set+=` for the actual explanation from Vim docs.

Comment: Actually the indentexpr could return cindent() for all lines except those blocks following a case... not too hard if you can match the right spots (searchpairpos will be useful).

Answer (score 2):

I put together a little function that defaults to using `cindent()` for the indent, unless we are indenting a `{` line that directly follows a case statement (I've been twiddling a lot with `indentexpr` lately):

```
function s:indent(lnum, offset) abort
  return a:lnum <= 0
        \ ? indent('.')
        \ : indent(a:lnum) + a:offset
endfunction

function! c#myindentexpr(lnum) abort
  if a:lnum <= 1
    return cindent(a:lnum)
  endif
  if getline(a:lnum) =~# '^\s*{' && getline(a:lnum-1) =~# '^\s*case'
    return s:indent(a:lnum-1, 0)
  else
    return cindent(a:lnum)
  endif
endfunction
```

Drop it in `~/.vim/autoload/c.vim`, and put the following line in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`:

```
setlocal indentexpr=c#myindentexpr(v:lnum)
```

You probably want to set `b:undo_ftplugin` as well.

---

I tested this on a couple of simple cases and it seems to be working.

Comment: You should post this on the [almost duplicate](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8718/vim-switch-statement-cindent-options) question, too.

Comment: ...or perhaps better, _just_ post it there and then close this one as a duplicate, as that one's a more general case.

Comment: @Rich good find; I read your earlier comments, but everything said « almost/not quite a dupe » so I didn’t actually look at the Q. I think it is a full dupe though, not sure sure how this Q differs in anyway. I’ll do both, I think.

Comment: I agree it's a dupe. The only difference is that this question doesn't have the requirement for it to work if there's no braces: it _only_ cares about the scenario where there is a block after the `case` label. If that question had had a _working_ answer, I'd have left my close vote anyway, but it seemed a bit mean to close this as a dupe when no full answer had yet been posted.